# selenium: is the first window handle always the main window?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is the first window guaranteed to be the main window? Or is the order random and inconsistent?

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}
```

I can't find any information about the order of the window handles, just a way to iterate thorugh them all. I am assuming that the first in the list of window handles is going to be the main window.

Comment: not language specific but an API one, as the webdriver docs do not mention

Comment: Main window as per my understandings is the one from which you have  invoked another window i.e. that first window in this scenario will be the parent window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the current [WebDriver API Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#window-handles):

> 6.3 Iterating Over Windows
>
> getWindowHandles
>
> An array containing a window handle for every open
>   window in this session. This array of returned strings must contain a
>   handle for every window associated with the browser session and no
>   others. For each returned window handle the javascript expression
>   "window.top.closed" (or equivalent) must evaluate to false at the time
>   the command is being executed.
>
> The ordering of the array elements is not defined, but may be
>   determined by iterating over each top level browser window and
>   returning the tabs within that window before iterating over the tabs
>   of the next top level browser window.

In short, no - there is no guaranteed order.

Comment: so you have to save the current window's handle, iterate through the handles and find it again? or does this mean that it will still attempt to return the handles in the order?

Comment: @user299709 that would be more reliable. Though I personally hadn't a situation with switching between selenium browser windows back and forth. Hope that helps anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As alecxe [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27632331/1906307) the handles can be in any order.

I solve the issue of *knowing which handle is the main window* by saving the handle immediately after I point Selenium to the first page to load (at this point the list of handles contains only one handle, which is the main window), and I save this value for future use. Then when I scan the list of handles later, I compare with the value I saved and know that handles that don't match it are not the initial window.

Doing this is useful in "tear down" or "clean up" code between tests in a test suite if you have *some* tests that *may* open other windows. Using the method I describe here, your tear down code can be generic and not worry about whether any specific test is *actually* opening additional windows.